# How can I say that a program runs at high load on the computer?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I've found "demanding", but I'm not sure if it sounds natural when talking about computers..

Comment: So you mean the program uses a lot of memory? Or that the program is slow to load, "Run at high load" doesn't sound right to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that it's **CPU-bound**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound):

> In computer science, a computer is CPU-bound (or compute-bound) when the time for it to complete a task is determined principally by the speed of the central processor: processor utilization is high, perhaps at 100% usage for many seconds or minutes. Interrupts generated by peripherals may be processed slowly, or indefinitely delayed.

---

An alternative is [*resource-intensive*](https://glosbe.com/en/en/resource-intensive%20task).